# Hidden Column in WebGrid (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webgrid

I'm trying to add Hidden values to my WebGrid so not even the columns would show. While the part with the `Html.Hidden` works just fine the columns are still showing. Any suggestions?

My `WebGrid`

```
WebGrid grid1 = new WebGrid(Model.StamfordRel, canPage: false, fieldNamePrefix: "g1", pageFieldName: "p1");       

        @grid1.GetHtml(
            headerStyle: "wg_header",
            columns: new[] {

            grid1.Column("logNo",
                header: null,
                format: (item) => Html.Hidden("logNo", (object)item.logNo),
                style: "width"),

            grid1.Column("instanceNo",
                header: null,
                format: (item) => Html.Hidden("instanceNo", (object)item.instanceNo),
                style: "width_logNo"),
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use set up with HTML:

```
grid1.Column("logNo",
      header: null,
      format: @<input type="hidden" name="logNo" value="@item.logNo"/>
      style: "width"),
```